# Select input choices are the unique value of the columns of file input .csv file

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to develop a shiny App where the y-axis variable would be the unique value of a column from an uploaded .csv file. Sp far, I can read the column names and set as choices in selectInput but not the unique values of the columns. my code for reading and selecting the column is

```
    library(shiny)

myData <- NULL
ui <- fluidPage(
  
  titlePanel("My R Shiny App"),
  
  sidebarPanel(
    
    fileInput(
      'file', 
      'Choose file to upload.'
    ),
    
    selectInput(
      "y_input", 
      label = h5("Select Time Series/Response Variable"),
      ""
    )
    
  )
  
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  inFile <- reactive({
    if (is.null(input$file)) {
      return(NULL)
    } else {
      input$file
    }
  })
  
  myData <- reactive({
    if (is.null(inFile())) {
      return(NULL)
    } else {
      read.csv(inFile()$datapath)
    }
  })
  
  observe({
    updateSelectInput(
      session,
      "y_input",
      choices=names(myData()))
    
  })
  
}
shinyApp(ui=ui, server=server)
```

the data set for example:

```
Geography   Measure Time    Value
abc Meause A    2011    4
abc Meause A    2012    5
abc Meause B    2013    6
cba Meause B    2014    7
cba Measure C   2015    8
cba Measure C   2016    9
bac Meause A    2011    10
bac Meause A    2012    4
bac Meause B    2013    5
abc Meause B    2014    6
cba Measure C   2015    7
bac Measure C   2016    8
```

For y-axis choices, I want the unique values of column Geography which are abc, cba, bac. Any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

<sub>Migrating the solution from [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48874667/select-input-choices-are-the-unique-value-of-the-columns-of-file-input-csv-file#comment84753312_48874667) by [sconfluentus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6258859/sconfluentus) to an answer:</sub>

> `choices =unique(df$Geography)` will return all possible values of the column Geography and save them to a variable you can use for a drop-down list.